# FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to learn PF so I started with displaying datatable first and navigating to next page on rowClick passing parameters, but got stuck with the following error. I found similar problem for that question but no luck yet. I hope somebody will help me out.

I am getting following error:

```
DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.

Caused by:
javax.faces.FacesException - DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.
```

my Page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>Primefaces 3.1</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">          
            <p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.cars}" var="var" rowkey="#{var.model}" 
            selection="#{tableBean.car}" selectionMode="single">
            <p:column>  <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Model"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputText"
                                value="#{var.model}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Color"></h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="outputText"
                                value="#{var.randomColor}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column></p:dataTable>                               
        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

my bean Classes:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TableBean extends ListDataModel<Car> implements SelectableDataModel<Car>{

    private List<Car> cars;
    private Car car;

    public List<Car> getCars() {

        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        Car car1 = new Car();
        car1.setModel("BMW");
        car1.setRandomColor("Black");
        cars.add(car1);
        Car car2 = new Car();       
        car2.setModel("Audi");
        car2.setRandomColor("White");
        cars.add(car2);

        return cars;
    }

    public String onRowSelect(){
        System.out.println("Row Click!!!");
        return "otherpage";//Does this nav works???if not how???
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    @Override
    public Car getRowData(String pArg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Car pArg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }   
    }
```

OtherBean:

```
public class Car{

    private String model;   
    private String randomColor; 

    public String getRandomColor() {
        return randomColor;
    }
    public void setRandomColor(String pRandomColor) {
        randomColor = pRandomColor;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String pModel) {
        model = pModel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `#{tableBean.cars}` must implement `SelectableDataModel` if you don't specify the `rowKey` attribute on the `<p:dataTable>`.

You have however implemented it on the `#{tableBean}` instead. This is not right. You can find correct examples in the [PrimeFaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml). Basically, your `TableBean` class must look like this according to the showcase code example:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TableBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Car> cars;
    private Car car;
    private CarDataModel carsModel;

    public TableBean() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        // Populate cars here and thus NOT in the getter method!
        carsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Where the `CarDataModel` look like this (again, just copied from PrimeFaces showcase code example):

```
public class CarDataModel extends ListDataModel<Car> implements SelectableDataModel<Car> {  

    public CarDataModel() {
    }

    public CarDataModel(List<Car> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Car getRowData(String rowKey) {
        List<Car> cars = (List<Car>) getWrappedData();

        for(Car car : cars) {
            if(car.getModel().equals(rowKey))
                return car;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Car car) {
        return car.getModel();
    }

}
```

Finally use `#{tableBean.carsModel}` instead of `#{tableBean.cars}` as value of `<p:dataTable>`. Exactly as in the showcase example.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.carsModel}" var="car" ... />
```

Another, easier, way is to just specify the `rowKey` attribute on the `<p:dataTable>`.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.cars}" var="car" rowKey="#{car.model}" ... />
```

This way you don't need the whole `SelectableDataModel`. You only need to ensure that it's never `null` and always unique across the rows. See also [DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled, but I have already defined rowKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342524/datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamodel-when-selection/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, BalusC, I have couple of questions, what is the use of rowKey? Is it for the unique value for the column of the table being displayed? What if I have lets say 2 primary key in the same table. Another question is, What do you mean by if I use rowKey I dont have to implement CarDataModel, can you explain little bit...and also can you put some light on what selection attribute does in <P:table>.

Comment: The `rowKey` basically tells PrimeFaces what the unique identifier is of the row. The `selection` basically tells PrimeFaces where it has to get/set the references of selected rows. The point of `SelectableDataModel` is to be able to identify unique rows based on other criteria than what is already available by the row object itself (for which you would need `rowKey`).

Comment: What we do if there are 2 primary keys, what we do in such scenario?

Comment: Either use a composite key or create a `SelectableDataModel`.

Comment: Note that you may still get the same error even though you may have defined a rowKey attribute **if** the said attribute returns null (e.g. it's not initialized).

Comment: For a unique object identity `rowKey="#{car.hashCode()}"` would be ok? Depends on your `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementation of course, but if not overwritten it is unique for each instance.

Comment: @opfau: hashcode doesn't per definition represent identity of the class' instance (multiple different instances can have same hashcode, you see, `int` has a hard limit in available values), but equals does (and does not force a limit anywhere).

Comment: Indeed that's not a good idea even the `hashCode()` implementation depends on the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure to set the rowKey parameter in the bean method that populates the "value=.." of the datatable. Mine returned this error because the rowKey was null.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my project using a composite key for rowkey e.g.: rowKey="#{course.getCompositeKey()

Since I didn't have a compositeKey variable I simply created one in my Course Class (in your case the Car Class). The 2 primary keys are strings so I just said this.compositeKey=this.courseNumber+this.product--you just use whatever 2 primary keys are in your Car class instead of courseNumber and product.

Answer (score 0):

Youd on't have to implement the datamodal in your managedbean, just  specify in the proprety of the datatable   the   "rowkey"    like this:   rowkey="{mbean.atribute1}"
-- atribute1 must be diplayed in the data table column.

## Must

Comment: The rowkey param is *not* required to be displayed as a column in the data table.