# DataTable with RadioCheckbox blank

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need a DataTable with RadioCheckbox then found the link

[FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526857/facesexception-datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamode/12787526#comment17288675_12787526)

all I needed, but when running the page is blank and doesn't give exception.

Anyway I will post my code as well.

My xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
  <title>Primefaces 3.1</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
 <h:form id="form">
   <p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.cars}" var="var" paginator="true" rows="10"
    selection="#{tableBean.car}"
    selectionMode="single">
      <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Model"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="#{var.model}"></h:outputText>
      </p:column>
      <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Color"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
        <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="#{var.randomColor}"></h:outputText>
       </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TableBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Car> cars;
    private Car car;
    private CarDataModel carsModel;

    public TableBean() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();     
        Car car1 = new Car();
        car1.setModel("BMW");
        car1.setRandomColor("Black");
        cars.add(car1);
        Car car2 = new Car();       
        car2.setModel("Audi");
        car2.setRandomColor("White");
        cars.add(car2);       

        carsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {   
        return cars;
    }

    public String onRowSelect(){
        System.out.println("Row Click!!!");
        return "otherpage";//Does this nav works???if not how???
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }    

    public CarDataModel getCarsModel() {
    return carsModel;
    }


    public void setCarsModel(CarDataModel carsModel) {
    this.carsModel = carsModel;
    }
```

CarDataModel:

```
public class CarDataModel extends ListDataModel<Car> implements SelectableDataModel<Car>, Serializable {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CarDataModel(List<Car> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Car getRowData(String rowKey) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Car> cars = (List<Car>) getWrappedData();

        for(Car car : cars) {
            if(car.getModel().equals(rowKey))
                return car;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Car car) {
        return car.getModel();
    }
```

I do not know what can be.

Thanks!

Comment: Already changed <p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.carsModel}" var="var" ..> unsuccessfully.

Comment: This is what I hate about facelets and jsf. Blank pages are the worst. No indication of what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
public TableBean() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();     
        Car car1 = new Car();
        car1.setModel("BMW");
        car1.setRandomColor("Black");
        cars.add(car1);
        Car car2 = new Car();       
        car2.setModel("Audi");
        car2.setRandomColor("White");
        cars.add(car2);       

        carsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
    }
```

You cannot put values to your list in the constructor.
If you move that code to the `getCars()` method, it should work

```
public TableBean() {}

public List<Car> getCars() {   
    if(cars != null && !cars.isEmpty()) return cars;
    else {
                  cars = new ArrayList<Car>();     
            Car car1 = new Car();
            car1.setModel("BMW");
            car1.setRandomColor("Black");
            cars.add(car1);
            Car car2 = new Car();       
            car2.setModel("Audi");
            car2.setRandomColor("White");
            cars.add(car2);       

            carsModel = new CarDataModel(cars);
    }
    return cars;
}
```

Comment: Without success Shervin! Using The Debug can see that he spends every step and returns a List <Car>, but nothing appears in the browser. To go through getCars switched to <p:dataTable value="#{tableBean.cars}" var="var"...>. I'm no idea on what can be. :/

Comment: When I run right at xhtml gives Warning: NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in:
  org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages. Very strange! If I close and open again this Eclipse Warning disappears.

Comment: DataTable could show by example: http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf;jsessionid=pQgttcgwYcTcGpZt_1qY0w. Now I can not show <p:dialog>