# DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled, but I have already defined rowKey

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectable, row-key

I've a selectable PrimeFaces 3.4.1 datatable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserMemberOfGroups}" var="group1" 
    rowKey="#{group1.name}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedBelongToGroup}">
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

I'm getting this error:

> com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
>   Grave: javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.

But I have already set `rowKey` as per [FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526857/facesexception-datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamode). How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 9):

This can occur when the EL expression in the `rowKey` attribute ever evaluates `null`.

Make sure that the `name` property of your `Group` instance is **never** `null`. Otherwise better use a property representing the autogenerated DB primary key, such as `#{group1.id}` — if you have one.

Comment: The group name is never null , but i tried the id and the error persist. should my managedBean implement SelectableDataModel ?

Comment: No, not your managed bean. The data model, exactly as the exception message says. The property behind `<p:dataTable value>`. Coming back to the concrete problem: well, sorry, exceptions don't lie. If you're using `rowKey` this way, then the only cause for this exception is that at least one of the items has a `null` group name. Perhaps the data loading logic is broken? Try to boil down a concrete SSCCE example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just FYI - I have experienced the same error when using the Primefaces column filters.  If I use the filters and click on a refresh button to reload the table, I then experience the error. If I don't use the column filters, then the error never occurs when I refresh the table.  I have a couple of column filters that perform filter logic on the same field that contains the full name by extracting either the first name or last name, so I suspect this issue is in relation to those filters.  I haven't figured out the issue yet but I wanted to share this with you in case that it helps. And I am using rowKey.

Comment: This sounds like a potentially useful comment to the question, but maybe not a definitive "answer" as such.