# javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled or define rowKey attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I saw this problem here many times but it doesn't help me.

I have the first dataTable with id:`servers` and I can do right click over a row and a contextMenu appears. I can click in `Show Process` and I get a second dataTable with id:`processes`.
But here is the problem, instead of showing the new dataTable I get,

> javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement
>   org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled or
>   you need to define rowKey attribute

But I have defined rowKey in both `dataTable`

I have this code:

```
<h:form id="form" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13">
    <!-- <p:messages id="msgs" /> -->
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true" />
    <!-- Context menu for servers table. -->
    <p:contextMenu for="servers">
        <p:menuitem value="Show processes" update="form" icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{homeBean.findLSRunningProcesses}" styleClass="homeIE"/>
    </p:contextMenu>
    <!-- Context menu for processes table. -->
    <p:contextMenu for="processes">
        <p:menuitem  styleClass="homeIE" update="@form" value="Stop Process"    icon="ui-icon-stop"     oncomplete="stopDialog.show()"/>
     </p:contextMenu>

     <!-- Servers table. -->
     <p:dataTable id="servers" var="server" value="#{homeBean.serverList}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                  paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                  rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" widgetVar="serversTable" rowKey="#{server.adminFQDN}"
                  selection="#{homeBean.selectedLogicalServer}" selectionMode="single" emptyMessage="No servers found with given criteria">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Servers" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.ASSETID}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{server.ASSETID}" headerText="ASSETID">
            <h:outputText value="#{server.ASSETID}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.adminFQDN}" filterStyle="width:240px;" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{server.adminFQDN}" headerText="FQDN">
            <h:outputText value="#{server.adminFQDN}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.adminIP}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{server.adminIP}" headerText="Admin IP">
            <h:outputText value="#{server.adminIP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.delivery}" filterMatchMode="exact" sortBy="#{server.delivery}" headerText="Delivery">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('serversTable').filter()">
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="false" />
                     <f:selectItems label="#{homeBean.deliveries}" value="#{homeBean.deliveries}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{server.delivery}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.environment}" filterMatchMode="exact" sortBy="#{server.environment}" headerText="Environment">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('serversTable').filter()">
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                     <f:selectItems value="#{homeBean.environments}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{server.environment}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.function}" filterMatchMode="exact" sortBy="#{server.function}" headerText="Function">
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('serversTable').filter()">
                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                     <f:selectItems value="#{homeBean.functions}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{server.function}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.osVersion}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{server.osVersion}" headerText="OS VERSION">
            <h:outputText value="#{server.osVersion}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{server.os}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{server.os}" headerText="OS">
            <h:outputText value="#{server.os}" />
        </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>

    <!-- Panel containing processes tables. -->
    <p:panelGrid id="serverProcesses" styleClass="group-user-selection-table" rendered="#{homeBean.showSelectionPanel}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.adminFQDN}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </f:facet>

        <p:row>

            <!--Processes table. -->
            <p:column>
                <p:dataTable id="processes" var="process" value="#{homeBean.processesList}" filteredValue="#{homeBean.filteredProcesses}"
                             selection="#{homeBean.selectedProcesses}" paginator="true" rows="15" rowKey="#{process.owner}"
                             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="15,20,25,30" selectionMode="single" emptyMessage="No processses found with given criteria">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Processes" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column name="owner" filterBy="#{process.owner}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{process.owner}" headerText="#{homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.os eq 'Windows' ? 'DESCRIPTION' : 'OWNER'}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.owner}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column name="pid" filterBy="#{process.pid}" filterMatchMode="exact" sortBy="#{process.owner}" headerText="PID">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.pid}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column name="ppid" filterBy="#{process.ppid}" filterMatchMode="exact" sortBy="#{process.ppid}" headerText="#{homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.os eq 'Windows' ? 'TYPE' : 'PPID'}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.ppid}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column name="c" filterBy="#{process.c}" filterMatchMode="exact" sortBy="#{process.c}" headerText="#{homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.os eq 'Windows' ? 'STATE' : 'C'}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.c}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column name="stime" filterBy="#{process.stime}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{process.stime}" headerText="STIME"  rendered="#{!(homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.os eq 'Windows')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.stime}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column name="tty" filterBy="#{process.tty}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{process.tty}" headerText="TTY"  rendered="#{!(homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.os eq 'Windows')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.tty}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column name="time" filterBy="#{process.time}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{process.time}" headerText="TIME"  rendered="#{!(homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.os eq 'Windows')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.time}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column name="cmd" filterBy="#{process.cmd}" filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{process.cmd}" headerText="#{homeBean.selectedLogicalServer.os eq 'Windows' ? 'NAME' : 'CMD'}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{process.cmd}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:dialog header="Stop Process" widgetVar="stopDialog" minHeight="40" styleClass="dialogPosition">
        <h:outputText    value="You are going to stop the process "/>
        <h:outputText    value="#{homeBean.selectedProcesses.cmd}"/>
        <h:outputText    value="with PID"/>
        <h:outputText    value="#{homeBean.selectedProcesses.pid}"/>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" style="float:left" onclick="stopDialog2.show();stopDialog.hide();" actionListener="#{homeBean.attrListener}">
            <f:attribute name="processPID" value="#{process.pid}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="NO" onclick="stopDialog.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" style="float:right"/>
    </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog header="Stop Process" widgetVar="stopDialog2" minHeight="40" styleClass="dialogPosition">
        <h:outputText    value="You are going to send an email to:"/>
        <br />
        <h:outputText    value="#{homeBean.email}"/>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <p:commandLink value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" style="float:left" update="form" action="#{homeBean.stopProcess}" oncomplete="stopDialog2.hide();"/>
        <p:commandButton value="NO" onclick="stopDialog2.hide()" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" style="float:right"/>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342524/datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamodel-when-selection/

Comment: The rowKey is never null. So I need to implements SelectableDataModel in the Process class?? @BalusC
I can't do `import org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel`

Comment: This worked when I was using the Version 4.0 of Primefaces and when I switched to version 5.0 has stopped working. @BalusC

Comment: Things improve over time. And 5.0? Are you migrating now? 5.1 is already not supported anymore

Comment: Me he equivocado estoy usando 5.1 @Kukeltje

Comment: english please (although I understand what you are saying)

Comment: [FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526857/facesexception-datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamode) this solution works to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526857/facesexception-datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamode) 
this solution works to me.

Especially this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10527008/5250930
The table must implement the `SelectableDataModel`